# Passing json array to php using ajax

Tags: ajax

I am using checkbox in the form and send to checkbox value to php using ajax request but it's not working show on erros check_List id undefined.Please give me a solution

```
 $.ajax({
     url : "response.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
   data: {check_List : JSON.stringify(values)},



    success: function(data){
            alert("OK");
        }


  });
```

**php code:**

```
if (isset($_POST["check_List"])) {

// Decode our JSON into PHP objects we can use

$myArray = json_decode($check_List, true);


echo "Data is: " . $myArray->data . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: do you have a var_dump of `$_POST['check_list']`? edit: you should declare your variable `$check_List = $_POST["check_List"];`

Comment: I have chekced but show following error  Notice: Undefined index: check_List in G:\xamp\htdocs\2015\css tricks1.6\response.php on line 17

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in G:\xamp\htdocs\2015\css tricks1.6\response.php on line 24